# Regarding Dice Array Program

Tags: java

--  I am to write a program that prompts for N which is number of dice to roll and M for number of times to roll. I must repeat M times N6 or six sided die and compute and record the total sum of rolls. Using an array i must report how many times along with a percentage each possible total from 6 to 6N occurred.

Here is my code so far, i cannot get it to compile, and i think im going about it completely wrong, we only have one professor that teaches java, and he is not good at explaining things and always seems to be in a hurry if we ask questions. This is my second division class, and i learned barely anything the first semester. 
////////////////////////////////

```
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Scanner;

     public class Lab1
    {
   public static Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
       public static void main (String[] args)

{
      int dice = 0;
        int roll = 0;
       while (true) 
     {
      System.out.print ("How many dice do you roll?");
            dice = in.nextInt();
       }


         System.out.print ("How many Times do you want to roll?");
           roll = in.nextInt();
           }
         int dicetotal = Dicecount (dice); //Error message. dice cannot be resolved to Variable//
         for (int i = 0; i< roll; i++)

         System.out.println (Dicecount (dice));
          }
       }
       public static int Dicecount ( int dice); 
         {
        int dicetotal = 0;
        for (int x = 0: x < dice; x++)
      {
         int rollcount = (int) (1+6* (Math.random()));
       dicetotal+=rollcount;}
     return dicetotal;
     }
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  As written your question is unlikely to get answered here.  What compiler errors are you getting?  What do you think is the problem?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: You'll get more responses if you provide the compiler error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properly format your code.  This will help you find that the 6 lines starting with:

```
int dicetotal = Dicecount (dice);
```

Are not within a function block, and need to be.

You also have a colon instead of a semi-colon in this line (~7th from the bottom):

```
for(int x = 0; x < dice; x++){
```

Fixing these errors will allow your code to successfully compile - but that doesn't mean that it will do what you want it to do.  Since [this is homework](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), you'll be expected to find these issues and at least do initial troubleshooting on them yourself.

Comment: right right, appreciate it. Thanks for a speedy reply, i overlooked those little errors. Alright will do, what is the policy on homework on this site? normally people are all against it, but im not asking anyone to do it for me, just to push me in the right direction ya know.

Comment: Thank you  for the info good sir! I fixed the errors but am having trouble with this one, its asking for a empty set but when i provide one it just keeps asking ?                                  { int dicetotal = Dicecount (dice);
     for (int i = 0; i< roll; i++)  /// Right here is where i am having the issue. What am i doing wrong?
   }

Answer (score 0):

Two other problems this code appears to have:

1) In Java method names should always start with a lower-case letter. Here you have a method called `dicecount`. This is an invalid name and will confuse the Java compiler.

2) On the line where you declare the Dicecount method, you have a semicolon right at the end. This is a syntax error and will cause your code not to compile or behave incorrectly. The reason for this is that the semicolon is essentially telling the compiler that the current line is a complete statement. But it isn't finished, you still need to declare the body of the method.

So my advice is to change this line `public static int Dicecount ( int dice);` to read like this `public static int dicecount(int dice)`. That is, remove the leading capital letter, and get rid of the semicolon at the end.